# Solving for Polynomial roots

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

This simple `Solve` gives the roots of a quadratic:

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
```

However, if I factor the polynomial in terms of its "unknown" roots `x1` and `x2`, this code does not work

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == (x - x1) (x - x2), {x1, x2}]
```

to solve for `x1` and `x2` (which in this case, we know, they are the roots found by the first code. **Why not? How can I code a solution in this spirit in mathematica?**

I need to find a way to employ a solution which is in the spirit of the second code, however, for the following reason.

In my real problem, I seek the roots of a degree 5 polynomial. Indeed, this general problem cannot be solved (see: Galois). However, in my case, several of the roots are given by known functions of the other roots. I plan to insert this information into the factored form on the RHS of code in the form of my second code above.

Comment: You are solving 2 variables with 1 equation; and Mathematica did give a correct answer. What answer do you expect?

Comment: Consider `SolveAlways[a x^2 + b x + c == (x - x1) (x - x2), x]`. But you do know the Vieta formulae, no? In that case, you can then use `SymmetricPolynomial[]`.

Comment: I understand it is fewer equations than variables, yes. But we know what the solutions `x1` and `x2` are, as they are given by the "quadratic formula" or the first code. How does this work? How is mma able to solve for both roots with only 1 equation in the first code but not in the second?

Comment: `SolveAlways[a x^2 + b x + c == (x - x1) (x - x2), x]` does not give the correct solutions for `x1` and `x2`

Comment: It was intended as a starting point; did you notice that you can get equations entirely in terms of `b`, `c`, `x1`, and `x2` from it, which you can then feed to `Solve[]`?

Comment: I see. That could be very helpful then. Can you help me with this though? `Solve[{a == 1, b == -x1 - x2, c == x1 x2}, {x1, x2}]` is not working (yields `{}`).

Comment: Remove the extraneous `a == 1` since it serves no purpose there. In any event, that could have been avoided by doing `SolveAlways[x^2 + b x + c == (x - x1) (x - x2), x]` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Reduce[ForAll[x, a x^2 + b x + c == a (x - x1) ( x - x2)], {x1, x2},Backsubstitution -> True]
```

gives you the solution you want.

Comment: Indeed it does, as I've posed it here. However, unfortunately this solution breaks already for degree 3, despite the Cubic Formula existing in general. `Reduce[ForAll[x, 
  x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c == (x - x1) (x - x2) (x - x3)], {x1, x2, x3}, 
 Backsubstitution -> True]` doe not work.

Comment: @Steve I am sleeping, can't test it now. But I remember in the reduce doc it says it does not use general formula for cubic equation by default, try adding the option Cubics->True.

Comment: Great work `happy fish`, you are right, that fixed it. Unfortunately, since no "`Quintics->True`" Option exists in mathematica, I still won't be able to employ this method for my problem...

Comment: @Steve, I don't know what you mean by "does not work"; by default, *Mathematica* uses `Root[]` to denote roots of polynomials. This is because, as you mention, not all roots admit explicit radical expressions.

Comment: Well, you're right. As we've said, Galois theory proves that the general quintic polynomial cannot be solved for closed-form roots, but I am hoping to solve a particular quintic for analytic roots, for which there is a symmetry among some of them which may reduce the complexity. It stands unknown whether my problem can be solved, but I would like to know if it fails because of improper programming in mathematica or because it is genuinely impossible to write the roots of this polynomial in closed-form.

Comment: @Steve, maybe you should ask another question with your *actual* problem. (As an aside, the roots of a quintic that cannot be expressed as radicals can nevertheless be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions or theta functions, which are admissible closed forms to advanced mathematicians. That is why "cannot be expressed as radicals" is a more precise statement.)

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to ask a simpler thing than my *actual* problem, which is more "research grade," I guess. But I think I will ask the real question here soon (or on math.SE) and see if anyone can help me. As a final thing, can you provide any insight on those closed forms for quintics? I suppose you are probably referring to something like this? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html At the moment, I must say that my prowess is likely insufficient to use that...

Comment: @Steve, yes, that page does note some of the special functions I mentioned.

Comment: I've posted my "real question" here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115766/finding-closed-form-eigenvalues-of-a-particular-matrix